# Searching for finding the graph connection of different mental disorders

Tags: brain-development, disorder

We are searching for finding the graph connection of different mental disorder. So I googled the `graph flowchart of  mental disorder slideshare` and find the below flowchart ([source](https://creately.com/diagram/example/i4ok5qaa2/Psychology-%20flow%20chart%20psychological%20disorders)):

[image]

If possible, I like to find out more flowchart like below and find some tags for finding academic paper about the `the graph connection of different mental disorder`

**Update:**

I am using the above flowchart for connecting the brain disorder graph which would by AI algorithms like these code (link [1](https://github.com/NeuromatchAcademy/course-content) and [2](https://colab.research.google.com/github/NeuromatchAcademy/course-content/blob/master/projects/fMRI/load_algonauts_videos.ipynb#scrollTo=dLhyvIwG29Ii)) and [project](http://algonauts.csail.mit.edu/challenge.html) for creating every disorder brain graph
by having the fMRI Photos of every disorder  and finally creating some flowchart like shown below:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder where are the personality disorders?

Comment: Thanks, @Ooker, the above photo ([link](https://creately.com/diagram/example/i4ok5qaa2/Psychology-%20flow%20chart%20psychological%20disorders)) is one flowchart with no description, which I guess it is not complete. So I asked here to find out some Academic paper tag for finding more complete chart like the above flowchart.